# What's the definition of $\operatorname{div}(u\otimes u)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

I've [found the symbol sequence $\operatorname{div}(u\otimes u)$ in a PDE](http://basilo.kaist.ac.kr/mathnet/thesis_file/JKMS-49-1-113-138.pdf). What is $\otimes$ in this context? The [outer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) product? Then $u\otimes u$ would be a matrix and hence it wouldn't make sense to me to take the divergence of it.

Comment: Please see here: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=CcTnaveQkn0C&pg=PA204&lpg=PA204&dq=div(u⊗u),+in+partial+differential+equations&source=bl&ots=FMcebs7_VE&sig=tBAiPjP_Mjb4I6jHxVb_ihn41P0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA5_ip9uHQAhXCnZQKHc5nBdsQ6AEIHTAB#v=onepage&q=div(u⊗u)%2C%20in%20partial%20differential%20equations&f=false

Answer (score 0):

Just searched in google and found [this link](https://books.google.ca/books?id=pMH_fEFdilMC&pg=PA486&lpg=PA486&dq=div%20u%20x%20u&source=bl&ots=LfjTWpTZ8l&sig=sXxZA7nQX91AxOLIuLKx7pVNYdI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisrYKNmuLQAhUk3IMKHYxpD28Q6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=div%20u%20x%20u&f=false)
$$\operatorname{div}(u\otimes v) = (\nabla u)v + (\operatorname{div}v)u.$$

Also, there is an explanation of your statement [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Divergence) using the notion of a tensor field.

I can't make out the meaning of this either, but it might help you...